# Confidence intervals for an even distribution with low resolution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, confidence-interval

My statistics classes are far behind me, so bear with me going forward.

Let *A* and *B* be positive real numbers. *B* is always an offset of *A*, to a small margin of error.

> *B* = *A* + *offset* ± *margin*

We can measure *A* and *B* repeatedly, but with the following caveats:

- Any measurements of *A* and *B* will be with a resolution *r*. That is, we can only ever know the integer *n* for which *A* is within [*n*·*r*,(*n*+1)·*r*[. The exact value of *r* is known and does not change.
- True value of *A* and *B* will change between measurements, although the offset stays the same. The distribution is even.

An example:

> *margin* = 1
>
> *r* = 10
>
> 1st set: we measure *A* to be within [20,30[ and *B* to be within [40,50[
>
> 2nd set: we measure *A* to be within [20,30[ and *B* to be within [30,40[
>
> 3rd set: we measure *A* to be within [10,20[ and *B* to be within [30,40[
>
> ...
>
> *N*th set: we measure *A* to be within [20,20[ and *B* to be within [40,50[

Given enough sets (a big enough *N*), we should be able to approximate *offset* through probabilities, to a certain confidence interval.

### How to calculate *N* for a desired confidence interval *p*? Or how to calculate *p* for a given *N*?

What is giving me trouble is the facts that the distribution is even and that there is an upper limit to the error in the approximation of *offset*, given by the resolution *r*. Also not sure how *margin* interacts here, but it is small enough that it could probably be disregarded.